# How to recompose a composable after an event occured in the main Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, compose-recomposition

I created an event listener to catch when a physical button is pressed, and it works well.
But I would want to update a `list` used in a `LazyColumn`

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
   @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContent {
           Theme {
               Surface(
                   modifier = Modifier                   .fillMaxSize(),
                   color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
               ) {
                   Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                       Greeting("Android")
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }

   @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
   override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
      // Handling event to get a text (type String)
      // ......

      //then updating my list
      myList+=newValue
   }


var myList: List<String> = mutableListOf()

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, paramBarcode: String) {
   var mutableList by remember {mutableStateOf(myList)}
   
   Button(onClick = {
      myList+= "new item"
      mutableList = myList
   }) {
      Text(text = "Add")
   }

   LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()            .padding(16.dp)
   ) {
       stickyHeader {Row(Modifier.fillMaxSize()                  .background(Color.Green)
           ) {
               TableCell(text = "Code", width = 264)
           }
       }
       itemsIndexed(items = mutableList, itemContent = {
          index, item ->
           Row(Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
           ) {
               TableCell(text = item, width = 256)
           }
       })
   }
}
```

If I try to `add` or `remove` an element of the `list` from my composable, everything is fine, but I can't get the same behaviour from my event.

I also tried to pass the `list` as a parameter to my composable, but it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [`SnapshotStateList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/SnapshotStateList) instead of an ordinary list as mutable state.

So instead of this

```
var myList: List<String> = mutableListOf()
```

try this,

```
var myList = mutableStateListOf("Item1")
```

and instead of using your ordinary list setting it with a new one every time you add an item, you can simply add new elements to a `SnapshotStateList`.

I modified your code and any changes coming from outside `Greeting` and inside of it reflects to `LazyColumn`

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(
     list: SnapshotStateList<String>
) {
    Button(onClick = {
        list.add("Item inside greeting")
    }) {
        Text(text = "Add")
    }

    LazyColumn(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) { ... }
}
```

Usage

```
setContent {
     Column {
          Button(onClick = {
                  myList.add("New Item Outside greeting")
          }) {}

          Greeting(myList)
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I still had to add this line above onCreate :     var myList: SnapshotStateList<String> = SnapshotStateList()

Comment: Actually, it didn't work as expected because I lost the remember property : re-composition deletes the current list if I rotate the screen.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it was about updating the `LazyColumn` outside of its composable scope not about surviving configuration changes, I tested your code and made a suggested fix. So If that's you're issue now then I suggest looking for a reference about `rememberSaveable`

Comment: Interesting, I'll try this maybe. I found something that works on recompose, I will just add it as a reply

Answer (score 0):

I've got a very good answer from [@x.y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19023745/z-y)

but then it lost value at recomposition.
Here is the updated code to handle my first problem while keeping the state of the list :

```
var MainList: SnapshotStateList<String> = SnapshotStateList()

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    var myList: SnapshotStateList<String> = MainList

    @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Theme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        Greeting("Android", myList)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
       MainList.add("$barcode")
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, paramBarcode: String, theList: SnapshotStateList<ScanItem>) {
    var mutableList by remember { mutableStateOf(theList) }

    Column() {
        Button(onClick = {
            MainList.add("ABC0000000000001")
        }) {
            Text(text = "Add item")
        }
        Row() {
            Button(onClick = { 
            MainList.add("add00001")
            }) { 
                Text(text = "Add")
            }
            Button(
                onClick = { MainList.clear() }
            ) {
                Text("Empty list")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I can pass mutableList as the parameter in itemsIndexed, and it will keep the state on recompose.

Comment: What is `ListScans`? You reference it in `dispatchKeyEvent()`, but you do not have a declaration for it, and it seems fairly important for your example.

Comment: typo, replaced "ListScans" with "MainList"